# How to show Cantor Lebesgue function is not absolutely continuous?

Tags: real-analysis

Just from their definitions without any other propositions or theorems?

Thanks for your hint!

Comment: (Assuming that you mean [this function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function))

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, thank you for pointing that out! By the way, could you please explain to me how to get the last equality in the first answer then? It seems quite obscure to me...